# I want to replace database file of an app made by me through another app

Tags: android

I have to **replace a file generated by an apk** in users device **with another file** in particular versions of current app.

I have no idea **how to accomplish this task** in android.

Can i make app B which when run replace the file of App A from App B??

Comment: Android is made such a way that one app can't modify files of another app. It's called security.

Comment: Why should you do this from another application? Can you specify the context

Comment: you can use `nosql` approch. store db file in `external folder` in encrypted format which has `json data` and you read through other app if you are having file location and beware of `marshmallow run time permission`

https://github.com/nhachicha/SnappyDB#create-database checkout this i don't know this might help or not

Comment: i also forgot to mention that using content provider you can share data between app. like phone contacts you can modify phone contacts with other app  using Content uri

Comment: I need to replace database file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Instead of that just provide the update of app A and do the same stuff. Then you are able to do the same.

Comment: I cant replace a file ?as i tried it manually i can able to replace.We are making downloads through ftp and not via google play.Need to replace databse file

Comment: if you have save the file on external storage then only you can do, if you are using internal storage and release build then, i don't think you can.

Comment: how to replace on external storage?

Comment: You know the path, where you are stored the DB file. Using app B, just make a new DB file with the same file name.

Comment: Yes i know the path .Using same path will replace the DB of App A??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, do the same implementation in the app B for DB.